# How can I create a rule in Microsoft Outlook for Android?

Tags: outlook

How can I create a rule in [Microsoft Outlook for Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.microsoft.office.outlook&hl=en)?

In the Microsoft Outlook web interface (OWA), I can do:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Creating and managing rules from the mobile apps is not currently supported. You can vote for [this request](https://outlook.uservoice.com/forums/293346-outlook-for-android/suggestions/9128254-rules) on Outlook's UserVoice if you'd like to show your support for it.

Comment: It looks like that UserVoice site is no longer in use: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/uservoice-pages-430e1a78-e016-472a-a10f-dc2a3df3450a

Answer (score 1):

You can use firefox and request desktop version of the website. This way you can use all desktop web features including rules and sweep.